# How to limit the output of certain categories in the blog on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to display only the specified categories in the blog.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The standard wp_list_categories function [has parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Include_or_Exclude_Categories) to include or exclude whatever categories you want.